# Doubts about plane waves in bitensor formulation

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, waves, differential-geometry, geodesics

I am currently working with bitensors and plane waves but I'm getting some results which don't seem to make sense and can't figure out why. So first of all we know that Synge's world function $\Omega$ corresponds to half the square geodesic length $\sigma$ and we therefore should be able to write
$$\Omega=\frac{\sigma^2}{2} \longrightarrow \nabla_\mu \Omega =\nabla_\mu \frac{\sigma^2}{2}=\sigma\nabla_\mu\sigma$$
But it's also known that the first derivative of the world function is $\nabla_\mu \Omega=\sigma t_\mu$, where $t_\mu$ is the unit tangent vector to the geodesic (Chapter II, paragraph 1 of Synge's Book *Relativity: The General Theory*). Can we conclude that $\nabla_\mu\sigma=t_\mu$?
Next, by taking the 4-divergence of the equation above one can find the following:
$$\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu\Omega-\nabla_\mu \sigma t^\mu=\sigma\nabla_\mu t^\mu$$
If what we said above holds and using the fact that (see *Eric Poisson, Adam Pound, and Ian Vega. “The Motion of Point Particles in Curved
Spacetime*) $\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu\Omega=d-\nabla_\mu(\ln{\Delta})\Omega^\mu$, where $\Delta$ is the Van Vleck determinant and d is the number of spacetime dimensions, then in flat spacetime where $\Delta=1$ we should be able to write
$$\frac{d-1}{\sigma}=\nabla_\mu t^\mu$$
Now this much could be true, the next point is that if I'm correct the tangent vector to a geodesic starting from the origin in flat spacetime should be equal to
$$t^\mu=\frac{x^\mu}{\sigma}$$
But if this is true and considering that $p_\mu=mt_\mu$, we should be able to write a plane wave as (I'm working in natural units $c=\hbar=1$)
$$e^{ip_\mu x^\mu}=e^{im\sigma}$$
But if we plug this in the Klein Gordon equation we obtain
$$(\partial_\mu\partial^\mu+m^2)e^{im\sigma}=[im(\partial_\mu\partial^\mu+im\partial_\mu\sigma\partial^\mu\sigma)+m^2]e^{im\sigma}$$
If $t^\mu = \partial^\mu\sigma$ then $\partial_\mu\sigma\partial^\mu\sigma=1$ but this can also be proven by the following reasoning
$$\partial_\mu\Omega\partial^\mu\Omega=\sigma^2\partial_\mu\sigma\partial^\mu\sigma=2\Omega=\sigma^2$$
Either way the KG equation above isn't respected since the term $im\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\sigma$ is non-zero (I believe) given that
$$\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\Omega = d=\partial_\mu(\sigma\partial^\mu\sigma)=\partial_\mu\sigma\partial^\mu\sigma+\sigma\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\sigma=1+\sigma\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\sigma$$
So somewhere here there must be some mistake, I suppose the plane wave cannot be written in that form but I can't see exactly why. I know i switched from covariant derivative to partial ones at some point but that's because I'm interested in the case of flat Minkowski space-time. Also I'm working with timelike geodesics and therefore not worrying about the $\sigma=0$ case. If anyone could help me shed some light on where the fallacy is I would appreciate immensely. Thank you!

EDIT:
I just noticed a completely equivalent problem arises if we compute the standard $\partial_\mu\partial^\mu e^{ip_\alpha x^\alpha}$ considering the momentum p not constant. So i suppose the problem is I don't exactly understand the assumption that p should be constant, and if the equivalences written in the question above hold then why would that imply that the geodesic length also is constant? I also would like to add that the plane wave written as $e^{im\sigma}$ resembles to me the integration measure used in gravitational path integrals, where the integration is over $\sigma$. Is this a coincidence?
And since were at it I find it strange that in writing something like $\partial_\mu \sigma= t_\mu$ am I not setting a bitensor (function of two events) equal to a regular tensor?